# github page blog from jekyll needs force reload to show changes with posts

Tags: jekyll, reload, github-pages

I'm learning a jekyll with github pages. When i create a new post (whatever how - locally and commit to github or online via github page) i need to force reload (ctrl+r) my page to see changes. Is it normal?

my repository url is [here](https://github.com/piotrekuczy/piotrekuczy.github.io)

Answer (score 1):

As Github pages content has http response headers like `Cache-Control:max-age=600` and `Expires:Wed, 10 Jun 2015 16:30:25 GMT` (a date ten minutes latter), the only way to avoid page caching is to setup your browser not to cache.

If your read carefully [this answer about http-equiv meta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49547/making-sure-a-web-page-is-not-cached-across-all-browsers/2068407#2068407) (read **HTML meta tags vs HTTP response headers paragraph**), you will understand that, in your case, **http-equiv meta are useless**.

And this cache has nothing to do with Jekyll but with github pages servers setup. A 10 minutes cache on a personal blog is not that big. A regular user will not need a refresh every 30 seconds.

And as a developer you are not supposed to develop on you production server, but on a development one, where you can specifically setup your server.

Comment: i have added these meta lines to my head.html but it not works. What is the point of using jekyll for blogging as a user must reload page?

Answer (score 0):

That's just browsers doing their thing. If you use the `published: false` Front Matter to work on drafts then you can conditionally disable caching using the following snippet in the `<head>` section of your post layout:

```
<% if page.published != true %>
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Tue, 01 Jan 1980 1:00:00 GMT" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<% endif %>
```

At the top of your work-in-progress:

```
---
layout: post
title: My New Article
published: false
---
```

When you want to publish for real, just remove the `published: false` YAML or set it to `true`.